# Can't integrate an mp4 video in my html page

Tags: html

I wanna integrate a video in my html page:
I tried this code:

```
<video controls="controls" width="400" height="222"> 
   <source src="D:\videos\test2.mp4" type="video/mp4">            
</video>
```

I get:

```
aucune video dont le format ou le type mime est géré n'a été trouvé
```

I tried also:

```
<source src="file://D:/videos/test2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

but I get the same thing!

contrariwise, when I tried:

```
<video controls="controls" width="400" height="200"> 
  <source src="http://www.nicolas-hoffmann.net/animations/Cavernae_Terragen2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

Here, the video is rendered for me!

Is it a problem with the video path?

Comment: `D:\...` isn't a valid ***URL***. At the very least it should be `file://D:...`.

Comment: I changed the url to src="file://D:/videos/test2.mp4" but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the video file at the same folder of your html page.
Then make a relative path like :

`./test2.mp4`