# Why my mp4 videos are not displayed in a html page?

Tags: html, video, mp4

I have read similar questions as this, but not with a solution to my problem. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69141597/mp4-video-not-displaying-in-html) one does not have a solution and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311349/cant-integrate-an-mp4-video-in-my-html-page) one I am already doing it. So

I have a simple html page and a video, *in the same folder* and the code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML Video embed</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Learn Eclipse</p>
      <br />
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="./pelicula.mp4" frameborder-"0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <video controls muted >  <source src="./pelicula.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
      <video controls>  <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
   </body>
</html>
```

As a result I have (this screen is in Windows 10)

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the video is not shown.
Btw, in windows when I double click the video I can watch it.
In linux this video has problems to play and I see an error message but in windows I see no error message, only the screen above

How can this be solved?

Comment: Could it be a codec problem? Perhaps mp4 isn't installed on your Linux installation by default?

Comment: Yes, I can guess that is the problem in linux and I plan to solve it *later*. But first I would like to know why it does not work in windows where the video can be played fine

Comment: try removing the ./ before the file name because sometimes file explorer commands can differ in operating systems

Comment: @Aaseer Tried it. It did not change

Comment: @DanielCheung It must be a codec problem because I tried another mp4 and both ways iframe and video (what is the difference btw) worked.  It is strange because the original video can be played by video applications in windows 10

Comment: @DanielCheung How can I discover what codecs are lacking?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by processing the video

```
ffmpeg -i pelicula.mp4 -vcodec h264 pelicula_264.mp4
```

Comment: I think there are still all sorts of possible causes behind. Your original video might have been in a weird format (audio video container format). Your video might have been partially corrupted. Your Windows player might have had the ability to process the special format or was lenient enough to overlook the video problems. In essence, I don't really know. But when in doubt, normalize the video like you did here I guess. XD